# Groovy script remove newline from StringBuffer

Tags: groovy

Thanks for taking the time to look into this.

How do I get rid of all newline characters from a StringBuffer?

The file that i'm reading in looks something like this -

```
USER|SLACK|TRELLO|BINARY|YO!##!
1234|Joe|||10001!##!
3212|Test1|||10001!##!
2213|Tin Man||24|10001!##!
```

I tried to use replaceAll(pattern,closure) like shown below. But somehow cant quite get my head around it.

```
package carriageReturnRemove

class asdf {


static void main(def args){

    String str = new File('C:/org.txt').getText()
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str)
    sb = sb.replaceAll(~'/n','')    

}
```

}

The output basically needs to look like this -

```
USER|SLACK|TRELLO|BINARY|YO!##!1234|Joe|||10001!##!3212|Test1|||10001!##!2213|Tin Man||24|10001!##!
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the lines and join them

```
new File('C:/org.txt').readLines().join()
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this too.

```
 new File("C:/org.txt").text.replaceAll("[\r\n]+","")
```

Comment: join is not deprecated

Comment: I don't conformed so i said "please check, it may be". @tim_yates